# How to get rid of the public path in laravel on wamp

Tags: wamp, laravel, virtualhost, public

I have a quick issue. I am trying to use Laravel for the first time. To do so, I'm using Wamp. And I don't know if this is important, but I set the DocumentRoot of wamp at this address :

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Bebop\Documents\Site Internet/"
```

I using wamp for a lot of different websites in a folder called Sites. When I access to one of the site I go to : localhost/Sites/thewebsite. So really what I want is just to get rid of the public folder in the path to the Laravel website.

For the moment I've did :

- Change httpd.conf of apache to include vhosts.conf :

  Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
- Created a new Virtual hosts and configured the directory like so :

  DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/LaravelTest/public"
  ServerName Sites/LaravelTest

  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1

After that I added a new host in the file located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       Sites/LaravelTest
```

By doing this, when I go to localhost I get redirected to the Laravel websites. But I would like to go to localhost/Sites/LaravelTest, because now I can't access to all my other websites.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Acess `localhost/Sites/LaravelTest/public` instead?

Comment: I don't really care in fact about accessing public, is more a question of understanding how it works that I'm asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to reach your Laravel site at: `http://localhost/LaravelSite/`

You can either use an alias in your `httpd.conf` file:

```
Alias /LaravelSite/ "C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/LaravelTest/public/"
<Directory "C:/Users/Bebop/Documents/Site Internet/Sites/LaravelTest/public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

or, create a symbolic link under command-prompt with the following:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\Bebop\Documents\Site Internet\Sites\LaravelSite" "C:\Users\Bebop\Documents\Site Internet\Sites\LaravelTest\public"`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. 

I have a last question though. Does this mean that I cannot use Laravel on a mutualized host or shared hosting, and that I have to have a dedicated host to use it ?

Comment: No, you can use Laravel on shared hosting. I do it using symbolic links.

Comment: When I use mklink on windows with Laravel, all my GET requests work, but I get a 404 on POST requests. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure that issue is related to mklink? Were your POST requests working prior to using mklink, i.e., for the `laravel/public/` path?