# Laravel separate URLs with a delimiter

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a very simple Controller for my static views.

```
Route::get('thisisatest', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.thisisatest');
});
```

I can access this view on domain.de/public/thisisatest

But i want to separate the url with a delimiter like domain.de/**this-is-a-test**.

How can i do this and how to remove the **/public** in my URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just type in what you want. In this case:

```
Route::get('this-is-a-test', function()
```

Please only ask one question per topic.

However, your question about `/public` is a duplicate and can be found here: [Laravel 4 removing public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586397/laravel-4-removing-public-from-url)