# Routing to domain root

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to set up a Laravel 4 environment, but when I'm linking to a sub-page it redirects immidiately to domain.com/route_name.

For instance on the page http://domain.com/public/ I have a link to a sub page called profile:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('profile', 'Profile') }}
```

In my routes.php it would look like this:

```
Route::get('profile',
  array(
    'as' => 'profile',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@getIndex'
    )
  );
```

But instead it redirects all requests to http://domain.com/public/profile to http://domain.com/profile. Why so? I haven't been able to find a setting for it yet.

**Edit**
Realised if I make a prefix (just anything), it will work, however it will load the URL http://domain.com/public/prefix/profile. So not a permanent solution.

Comment: why dont you have your webroot pointing to the public folder ?

Comment: Unfortunately my current host don't support it at the moment, so my dev server is setup like this. It's not optimal, but I'm waiting till I find an other host. But it works on another project I'm on, so I'm sure it's just a matter for some setting :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586397/laravel-4-removing-public-from-url

Comment: Nope that's not it. I'm forced to have a prefix, I'm not talking about public I'm talking about **prefix**. I can't get rid of /prefix/, well I can, but then nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not optimal, but you can probably modify the base URL in you `app/config/app.php` file to `http://domain.com/public`.