# Laravel get rid of /public path in wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I'm using Laravel on WAMP server. 
I have a hard time to get rid of /public/ in the URL path.
I found many workarounds on the web but no solution is working for me. I changed my .htaccess, my httpd.conf,... tried to make a symbolic link through windows console, but still nothing working.

Here's my .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8080/blog$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8080/blog$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
  RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Hereafter my httpd.conf

```
# Alias for Laravel public directory
Alias /Lara/ "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.31-0/apache2/htdocs/blog/public/"
<Directory "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.31-0/apache2/htdocs/blog/public/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586397/laravel-4-removing-public-from-url)

Comment: have you tried restarting your apache?

Comment: Yes I did, many times.