# Laravel url without public folder

Tags: laravel

hi i am using  `wampserver` for my project 
and my project is in folder `sss`
so i must type this Url `localhost\sss\public`
and want to have this

```
localhost\sss\
```

to show my index page

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586397/laravel-4-removing-public-from-url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the public folder contents outside the public folder and open index.php which you copied outside the folder, than change the:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

and you can access directly.