# Laravel4 remove public from URL

Tags: laravel-4

I am working on laravel project and deploye it on Hostgator server.

Everything is working fine but I don't want to run my site like `www.xyz.com/public`. I want to remove `/public` from the url. For this, I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-i-can-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laraveL#answers) (**Method II : Moving the contents of public folder to root directory**).  After this my Home page is working fine on `www.xyz.com`. But when I try to access `www.xyz.com/about` or `www.xyz.com/admin` it returns a 404 page, "not found error".

I am new to `laravel` can someone suggest me what should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 removing public from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586397/laravel-4-removing-public-from-url)

Comment: Set the document root to /public (production mode). There's a reason why the public folder exists! Don't give access to your root folder!

Answer (score 1):

Just follow below steps:

1.Create a folder `myappnamebase` in your document root folder

2.Put all your contents of the application except the public folder content to myappnamebase folder

3.Put all your public folder content in `public_html` folder

Then bring the following changes:

Inside  public_html->index.php

instead of

```
 require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

add

```
 require __DIR__.'/../myappnamebase/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

instead of

```
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

add

```
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../myappnamebase/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Inside myappnamebase->bootstrap->paths.php do editting so that it looks like following

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../myappnamebase/app',

'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',

'base' => __DIR__.'/../myappnamebase',

'storage' => __DIR__.'/../myappnamebase/app/storage',
```

Finally dont forget to upload .htaccess in the `public_html` folder. It should look like following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```