# Moved my laravel 5.3 project from a server to other and I got a lot of issues

Tags: php, laravel

I just moved my app from a AWS EC2 server to another.
I deploy with GitHub, so, everything should be smooth.
 a
But I got a lot of issues:

When I try to login with user / Pass, I get:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

When I try to login with socialite ( Google / FB ) I get:

```
Socialite: InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php Line 200
```

I manage a plugin https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation, that I also give error

Off course, in local, everything works fine ( I use Laravel valet )

I can't figure out what is the common point between all those elements.

What I did :

```
composer install
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artian vendor:publish
composer clear-compiled
php artisan migrate -seed
gulp
copied my old .env to the new server ( it's not automatically deployed )
```

I also checked my storage/framework/sessions folder had write permission.
EDIT: My guess is there is a problem with sessions, but don't really know what... CRSF Field works with session. Also AbstractProvider issue appears to be a session problem. I tried to change session from file to DB, but with no result.

Any idea why is there so many errors?

Comment: Check your .env file for starters, make sure it's identical (it's often not versioned in git, and you didn't mention it).

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying... I copied my old .env

Comment: If the token is salted using some env var or characteristic, all your hashed passwords are invalid now.
If your app integrations (google, fb, etc...) was registered using a token and server ip... well, that changed too.

Comment: I guess it would deny login, but not giving me a csrf issue, don't you think?

Comment: pass are just create with bcrypt.

Comment: I think this is somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696893/move-laravel-project-to-new-server?rq=1

Comment: It seems an example of what it should be.... In this case, user had no issue when migrating... Just changing DB settings...

Comment: It could be a session issue

Comment: Your app url has not changed?

Comment: nop. I maintain the same url: https://my.kendozone.com

Comment: You was need specify subdomain for session in old installation. Have you specified it for current (in config/sessions or .env file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read a lot of cases, but none got my solution.

I solved it changing

```
APP_ENV=testing
```

to

```
APP_ENV=test
```

in my .env file

One more solution to this problem, hope it helps!

Stupid, but very time consuming!!!