# Install Laravel 5 app in subdirectory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-routing

## The Setup

I am trying to install a laravel 5 app in this directory on my server:

`public_html/myapp/`

And I want it to be accessed at this URL:

`http://www.example.com/myapp/`

I have created this .htaccess rule and placed it in the `myapp` folder in order to redirect requests :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

## Problem:

In my browser when I try to access the app I get redirected URLs like:

- `http://www.example.com/myapp/public/index.php`
- `http://www.example.com/myapp/public/index.php/dashboard`

instead of nice pretty URLs like:

- `http://www.example.com/myapp/`
- `http://www.example.com/myapp/dashboard`

What do I need to change in my .htaccess file to get proper URLs working?

---

Update: The laravel app can be moved elsewhere if needed, as long as the desired URL structure above (with the app accessible at example.com/myapp/) can be achieved.

Update: When I try to access `example.com/myapp/dashboard` I receive the following error message in the browser: `NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 7793:` with a stack trace that starts with:

```
in compiled.php line 7793
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7066
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7038
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7030
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 1989
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
```

Update: The following .htaccess file is located in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have htaccess file within public folder also?

Comment: Doesn't installing the app in public_html make all your Laravel files accessible to everyone?

Comment: Hmm, probably does. If I install outside of public_html, how would I point to it with .htaccess? (Would accept that as a valid answer too as long as it achieves the URL structure I am hoping for)

Comment: @BenCole how did you finally setup the app? Did you do it using a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 14):

What you can do is use a **symlink**.

1. Place your laravel app somewhere else (outside the public_html folder)
2. Create a symlink of your app's public folder inside the public_html folder

   cd /path/to/your/public_html

   sudo ln -s /path/to/your/laravel_app/public myapp

> You can read more about symlinks [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

Answer (score 8):

You can easily achieve this by adding additional `.htaccess` file in the `myapp` folder (this will redirect all of your requests in `myapp` folder to the `public` as it should):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You should also modify the `.htaccess` in your `myapp/public` directory, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /myapp/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The change here is that you rewrite the base path `RewriteBase /myapp/`

Comment: I still seem to be having the same problem. The rewrites do work for plain text files, however when I try to access index.php I get redirected as described originally. I'll update the original question with one more error message I noticed in case that helps figure out what is going on.

Comment: Please remove your `.htaccess` from the public folder and put mine that I have suggested you.

Comment: I did replace the `myapp/public/.htaccess` file with the one provided, and I also replaced "myapp" with the name of the app folder as well. Also cleared the browser cache just to be sure.  Same redirect issue. The rewrite rules you provided look good to me, so maybe there is something else going on with the routes in the app? I'm not really sure.

Comment: Please provide in your question the content of your routes.php

Comment: Btw please run `php artisan clear-compiled` before that.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, but with the **RewriteBase** parameter it was possible to fix it.

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my_app/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -2):

This example should work for following cases:

- Regular domain: http://example.com
- Subdomain: http://myapp.example.com
- Subfolder: http://example.com/myapp

Follow these steps:

1. Move everything from **myapp/public** folder to **myapp/** folder
2. Open **myapp/index.php** and update bootstrap paths to **require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/**
3. Open .env and update to your base url like: **APP_URL=http://example.com/myapp**
4. Update paths in all views and layout (also in the code if you have any) to use base url, like this: 
   **src="{{URL::to('/js/app.js')}}"**

It's always recommended to separate public folder from the rest of your app. You can add some protection to Laravel folders by adding .htaccess files inside them that will contain "**Deny from all**".