# Laravel project setup into hosting server

Tags: laravel, installation, server, project

I have a Laravel 5 project into WAMP and it is working in localhost:8000.
I need to setup this project into staging server. So the URL will be like 156.34.22.11/example/laravel/public. How to setup my project into other server?

Answer (score 0):

Point web server to a `public` directory, restart web server. Set correct permissions on a storage directory. If you're using Linux:

```
chmod -R 775 storage
```

Run `composer update` command and clear the app cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259162/1227923

Comment: Instead of copying the answer, mark it as possible duplicate.

Comment: @RobinDirksen, I didn't copied. Wrote the answer then remembered I've answered similar question and added cache clear commands and link to old answer.