# Uploading laravel 5.2 in server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ftp

I have successfully uploaded all files of my laravel project to server, but it always displays 'page not found' error. the root directory donot have `public_html` folder. so i tried renaming public folder of laravel to `public_html` but it is still not working. It is still up and running in localhost.

update:
moved all public directory files to root directory now got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: Did you tried to up just one index.php file with only a "echo" to see if the server is working on this directory?

Comment: yes. i tried the url `../public/images/img.jpg` and it is displaying the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup web server. Create a virtual host and set `/yourLaravelProject/public` directory as root. Restart web server.

Also, set correct permissions to a `storage` directory:

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

After that I'd recommend to [clear all Laravel cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259162/1227923):

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Usually after these steps Laravel app works as expected.