# Laravel 5.2 upgrade to 5.3 flash message error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

After the upgrade from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 I'm not able the add the Flash message.

This is the code we use:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('alert-success', 'My Message');
```

And for displaying the message:

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
        <div class="alert alert-{{ $msg }} alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            {{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }}
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

We also cannot use the login messages if we provider wrong credentials:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used 5.2.27 or lower and moved to 5.3, most definitely you've used `web` middleware in routes file. You need to [move `web` middleware from Laravel 5.3 routes to make sessions work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade), because since 5.2.27 if you're trying to add it manually to `web.php`, it brakes sessions related functionality.

Comment: Do not return `web` middleware to `web.php`, keep it removed. Try to [clear all Laravel cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259103/laravel-application-is-not-working-after-uploading-to-the-server/37259162#37259162). Also, check `app\Http\Kernel.php`. In 5.3 and latest 5.2.x in it's different. [Here's](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php) how it looks like in 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can with an edit in the `Kernel.php`.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

When I added the `StartSession` and `ShareErrorsFromSession` it worked as the old site would.