# Update Function is UsersController only saving for one field

Tags: laravel

I am currently running into an issue with my update function in my UserController. The only field that will update correctly is the eid field, all other fields just cause the page to refresh.

I have looked at several other update function examples and I can't determine what

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'eid' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
    ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->eid = $request->eid;
    $user->email = $request->email;
     if (!empty($request->password)) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    }
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('users.show', $id);
```

edit.blade.php

```php
<form action="{{route('users.update', $user->id)}}" method="POST">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            {{method_field('PATCH')}}
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
                <p class="control">
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" value="{{$user->name}}">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="eid" class="label">EID</label>
                <p class="control">
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="eid" id="eid" value="{{$user->eid}}">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
                <p class="control">
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="{{$user->email}}">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>

                <p class="control m-t-10">

                    <input type="text" class="input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                </p>
            </div>
            <button class="button is-success is-pulled-right" type="submit">Update User</button>
        </form>
```

Migration File

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('eid');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

dd results

```
array:5 [▼
"_token" => "uG3qvyPAa2OBGFUZ7PNwNRKhupNyQLeptxHsSi8a"
"_method" => "PATCH"
"name" => "Agent11"
"eid" => "RQrOwau11"
 "email" => "agent12@app.com"
]
```

dd after validation

```
User {#271 ▼
#fillable: array:4 [▼
0 => "name"
1 => "eid"
2 => "email"
3 => "password"
]
#hidden: array:2 [▶]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:8 [▼
"id" => 6
"name" => "Agent11"
"eid" => "RQrOwau"
"email" => "agent@app.com"
"password" => "$2y$10$KC3UVyoLPhtb/omRT8gxjuHe/QB8t5Lj/JYLugbHMfQ9O4NyduV5a"
"remember_token" => null
"created_at" => "2017-12-19 15:21:23"
"updated_at" => "2017-12-21 10:33:40"
]
#original: array:8 [▼
"id" => 6
"name" => "Agent11"
"eid" => "RQrOwau"
"email" => "agent@app.com"
"password" => "$2y$10$KC3UVyoLPhtb/omRT8gxjuHe/QB8t5Lj/JYLugbHMfQ9O4NyduV5a"
"remember_token" => null
"created_at" => "2017-12-19 15:21:23"
"updated_at" => "2017-12-21 10:33:40"
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
#rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
```

dd after save

```
User {#271 ▼
#fillable: array:4 [▼
0 => "name"
1 => "eid"
2 => "email"
3 => "password"
]
#hidden: array:2 [▼
0 => "password"
1 => "remember_token"
]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
 #keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:8 [▼
"id" => 6
"name" => "Agent11"
"eid" => "RQrOwau"
"email" => "agent@app.com"
"password" => "$2y$10$KC3UVyoLPhtb/omRT8gxjuHe/QB8t5Lj/JYLugbHMfQ9O4NyduV5a"
"remember_token" => null
"created_at" => "2017-12-19 15:21:23"
"updated_at" => "2017-12-21 10:50:46"
]
#original: array:8 [▼
"id" => 6
"name" => "Agent11"
"eid" => "RQrOwau"
"email" => "agent@app.com"
"password" => "$2y$10$KC3UVyoLPhtb/omRT8gxjuHe/QB8t5Lj/JYLugbHMfQ9O4NyduV5a"
"remember_token" => null
"created_at" => "2017-12-19 15:21:23"
"updated_at" => "2017-12-21 10:50:46"
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
#rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}
```

Comment: your user model should have protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'eid', 'password'];

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi no, it shouldn't because OP doesn't use mass assignment.

Comment: Leo, I am pulling in App\User at the top of the file which has my $fillable in it

protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'eid', 'email', 'password',
    ];

Comment: @darkdelusions please post results of `dd($request->all());` and migration file for `users` table.

Comment: @darkdelusions right I see your issue  <button class="button is-success is-pulled-right">Update User</button>    add type = "submit"

Comment: But OP says `eid` is updating normally, this means the form is working. Maybe he's using JS or something to submit the form.

Comment: well if he is using js then we need that info! @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin results above for formatting reasons

Comment: @darkdelusions the request array looks fine too. What about the migration file?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin posted it above as well here is the github for my code base https://github.com/darkdelusions/support

Comment: The code looks fine except the submit button. Maybe you're using some kind of cache (OPcache or something)? Also, try to [clear all Laravel cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259103/laravel-application-is-not-working-after-uploading-to-the-server/37259162#37259162).

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin corrected the submit button when leo suggested it, and just cleared all the cache and no go and I have no cache plugins

Comment: @darkdelusions well, it's super weird. Put `dd(User::find($id));` right after validation (before the `$user = User::...`) and please post results. Then put the same `dd(User::find($id));` right after `$user->save();` and post results for this too and also please update `dd($request->all());` results for the same request. But when you'll do that, do not fill the form again and again, just change the code and press refresh button in browser to make sure the data is the same for all three `dd()`.

Comment: I've found that confirming changes can be done with a `$originalAttributes = $model->getAttributes(); ... $model->save(); ... $newAttributes = $model->getAttributes(); ... dd($originalAttributes, $newAttributes);`; should show the values before and after a save in the same `dd()` statement.

Comment: Try `dd($errors->all())` in your view to see any validation errors.

Comment: @MartinBean but OP said `eid` was updated and other fields weren't.

Comment: @darkdelusions I've looked into the `dd` results and I don't see `eid` was updated as you've said before. Also, you're using the same name as it was before.

Comment: @MartinBean that solved the issue, when i added the dd($errors->all()) to the view it returned an error because i had eid set to unique:users preventing the form from posting 

This can be marked solved.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin thank you for all your help as well