# Laravel application on sub-directory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The laravel application seems to have routes issue with the **sub-directory** on server. With the running application on **local** machine does not work on **temporary domain** in sub-directory on live server. Playing around `.htaccess` seems to have different results.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497575/install-laravel-5-app-in-subdirectory-with-htaccess) is almost identical to what I would be looking for but he hasn't got any solution while I have got some work around.

The `.htaccess` within the laravel `public` have been modified to something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /~timely/email-client  //<--base has been modified
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[The application](http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/) will redirect you to [host gator 404 page](http://gator4057.temp.domains/404.html).

Also I've added `.htaccess` to the main directory which will forward every request to `public` directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Upon removing the **home/main** `.htaccess` just works for `/` route: e.g

`http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/public` will work but all other routes are redirected to the same **host gator 404 page**.

Your comments and answers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, do you want your laravel project run on ```http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/```, right?

Comment: @HenryBui yup that's what I'm looking for

Comment: I think it couldn't because when you go to `http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/public`, host can understand must go to ~timely/email-client/public. But when you go to `http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/xxx`, your host don't understand. Did you try `http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/public/xxx`

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: Do you have laravel code in this dir? MyUser/public_html/[laravel code here] ? I mean on server inside public_html

Comment: This question has been asked from seniors those who an idea. Please don't comment if you are beginner.

Comment: Hey I'm not beginner in laravel but yes of course here on stackoverflow. BTW you can move /public/index.php file along with other files to root directly but you have to do some changes in index.php also. Don't need to change anything in .htacces.

Comment: @JinandraGupta I can't move all of the code to `root` directory. There is already an application running on `public_html`

Comment: Ok, then create a sub-directory inside public_html/laravelcode/
and move public file inside /public_html/laravelcode/[ all public files here]

Comment: @JinandraGupta The application is within the `public_html` directory.
e.g `public_html/email-client`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Move all email-client/public to email-client/. Now we're getting somewhere. Warning: Don't forget to copy the .htaccess file too

**Step 2**. Open email-client/index.php in your favorite editor and change

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../email-client/bootstrap/app.php';
or may be
$app = require __DIR__.'/email-client/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and change:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php'
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'
or may be
require __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'
```

Run command:

```
php artisan cache:clear  
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

> OR

If you dont wana to do more changes try this:

Put this in index.php file

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
}
```

Hope work for you.

Comment: Just take a look at this url. It works but all other `uris` are redirected back to `404` page.

http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/public/

Comment: I checked that If I manually type login page or registration page like http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/login , http://gator4057.temp.domains/~timely/email-client/register these both are also not working.

Comment: I've done some changes in my answer. Please try the below one in index.php file on top. Also replace RewriteBase /~timely/email-client 
 by  RewriteBase / in .htaccess file.