# Routing in Laravel and httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, routes, httpd.conf

I've set my document root as follows:

```
c:/wamp/www/laravel/public
```

When I test localhost on the browser I get the "You have arrived" page.

However when I try localhost/page0, I get a 404.

In my routes.php file I have this:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('page0', function() {
    return 'Test Helloworld! 0';
});
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It looks like everything should work. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Is there anymore tests you can do like: `return View::make('hello');` from your `page0` route?

Comment: I tried: localhost/index.php/page0 and this works. How can I make it work just doing: localhost/page0?

Comment: Sounds like your apache rewrite module is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check if mod_rewrite is enabled by doing:

```
phpinfo();
```

You can issue this in your `routes.php`.

It is also possible to start a webserver in php like so from the terminal or command prompt depending on your OS:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public/
```

Do this from your project root. Then you can go to:

```
localhost:8080
```

And your site should be up and running. You can still use the MySQL server that is running from XAMPP or WAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
c:/wamp/www/laravel/public/page0
```

This should work.

For production and/or development you can set the document root to the "public" folder, to get rid of the "/public/" in your url:

@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469480/1854296 (for example)